# Visual Basic using SQL Database

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

So this is a homework question but I'm probably missing something really simple. I am working on a project where I was given a database. I'm not in the programming part of the assignment but I have to write the test case scenerios for the project before starting the project. Because I am working with an SQL Database that was provided. I am supposed to write the expected output from the database. If the user chooses shampoo from the products menu then the different brands of shampoo should then populate in my datagrid.

Because they gave us a sample database. How do I view it? I am I supposed to be able to write the expected output if I don't know what has been pre-programmed into the database?

Thanks in advance. I have already designed my layout and I guess I'm just stuck because I have been taught to plan your output before you program that way you know the program is working correctly. I don't want to write the assignment to find my output in case I did it wrong I guess, if that makes sense.

Comment: Did they give you a backup of the database (e.g. `.BAK`)? Did they maybe give you remote server credentials?

Comment: @neoistheone I was just given the database file. no .BAK.

Comment: How does your db's filename look like?

Comment: @peterm NORTHWIND.MDF

Comment: OK. Do you have any edition of SQL Server installed on your machine? If yes than you just have to attach your database using SQL Server Management Studio or Servers panel in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it in Visual Studio 2010

> **[To create a data connection to the Northwind database—SQL Server
>   database file (.mdf)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384568%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**
>
> - On the View menu, click Server Explorer/Database Explorer.
> - In Server Explorer/Database Explorer, right-click Data Connections and
>     click Add Connection.
> - After you click Add Connection, either the Add Connection dialog box
>     or the Choose Data Source dialog box will appear.
> - If the Choose Data Source dialog box appears, select Microsoft SQL
>     Server Database File, and then click OK.
> - If the Add Connection dialog box appears, verify that the Data source
>     is set to Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient). If it is not
>     set to Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient), click Change to
>     open the Change Data Source dialog box, click Microsoft SQL Server
>     Database File, and then click OK.
> - Click Browse to locate the .mdf file that contains the Northwind
>     database.
> - Depending on the requirements of your version of the Northwind
>     database, either click Use Windows Authentication or click SQL Server
>     Authentication and type a user name and password to log on to the
>     computer running SQL Server. For more information, see Add/Modify
>     Connection (Microsoft SQL Server Database File).
> - Click OK.
>
> A data connection to the Northwind database is added to Server
>   Explorer/Database Explorer.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thank you so much. I can add the database to my project but how to I actually see what is in it? Or would that mean I have to start programming the program now to be able to view it? I'm still confused on that part. Thanks again.

Comment: @JeremyB You can use the same Explorer/Database Explorer. If you drill down to the `Tables` node and right click on a table you can then click on `Show Table Data` context menu item and it will bring a window with data in that table.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this should be pretty straight forward then:

1. Download and install [SQL Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8961).
2. [Attach the database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx).

I wouldn't normally just list links in an answer, but this one really calls for it. These are very foundational URL's and won't be moving.